# $( \forall k \in \mathbb N ,\, n \neq k^2 \implies \sqrt{n} \not \in \mathbb Q)\implies \sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3} \not \in \mathbb Q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Assuming the truth of the theorem that states that
$\sqrt{n}$
is irrational whenever
$n$
is a
positive integer and that is not a perfect square, prove that
$\sqrt{2}$
+
$\sqrt{3}$
is irrational.

Comment: Rolling back the previous edit. I think that the question was changed in an essential way by the removal of the fact that the square roots of non-square integers are irrational. Clearly a part of this exercise is to allow the solvers to assume that fact as known.

Answer (score 10):

Hint: assume $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ is rational, then square it. Arrive at a contradiction.